# Vaadin project-local node/npm installation using Gradle plugin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm building multiple Vaadin UI projects in a CI build, and they have different Vaadin versions which require different Node / NPM versions. The use of the global and .vaadin installations is causing me headaches, so I want to switch to project-local installations, because the [documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/configuration/development-mode/node-js) says:

> A project-local installation always takes precedence over a global or ~/.vaadin installation.

I'm using Gradle. The [documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/guide/start/gradle) explicitly mentions

> - Node.js and npm, which is optional because they can also be installed locally to the project using the Vaadin Gradle plugin.

However, I couldn't find how to trigger this installation.
There are only 3 vaadin-specific Gradle tasks:

- vaadinBuildFrontend
- vaadinClean
- vaadinPrepareFrontend

The [GitHub page for the Vaadin Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/tree/main/flow-plugins/flow-gradle-plugin) only mentions [this](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/tree/main/flow-plugins/flow-gradle-plugin#automatic-download-of-nodejs-and-npmpnpm) regarding `$HOME/.vaadin` installation:

> ### Automatic Download of node.js and npm/pnpm
>
> Since Vaadin Gradle Plugin 0.7.0, you no longer need to have node.js nor npm installed in your system in order to use Vaadin. Vaadin will download the node.js and npm (and pnpm if pnpmEnable is true) and will place it into the $HOME/.vaadin folder.
>
> This functionality is triggered automatically, you do not need to call a Gradle task nor configure your CI environment in any special way.

But nothing related to project-local installation.
Would it be possible to let it install a version in `$HOME/.vaadin` and then move this installation to `[project_dir]/node`?